# How to have Ellipsis effect on Text

Tags: react-native, ellipsis

I'm having a long text in my app and I need to truncate it and add three dots to the end.

How can I do that in React Native Text element?

Thanks

Comment: You've been given the perfect answer. Maybe you should accept it?

Comment: The fact there is so many up votes , shows there should probably be a component for this or a prop at least.

Comment: @LUser there is: `<Text>` and `numberOfLines`

Answer (score 105, accepted):

use numberOfLines

```
<Text numberOfLines={1}>long long long long text<Text>
```

or if you know/or can compute the max character count per row, JS substring may be used.

```js
<Text>{ ((mytextvar).length > maxlimit) ? 
    (((mytextvar).substring(0,maxlimit-3)) + '...') : 
    mytextvar }
</Text>
```

Comment: That's not a solution. Text is variable width.

Comment: As long as the container of the Text element has a Flex value (I use, 1), the text will be truncated within the container. So @Rahul Chaudhari's answer is the way to do it.

Comment: numberOfLines={1}

Comment: The link provided is broken and the solution should be to use react-native's built in support for this which is explained in other answers.

Comment: Is there any styling for the `<Text>` for handling the long text? As i am facing that issue for `<ListItemText>` in `material ui` and i am not able to find any answer for that

Comment: I'm having issues with numberOfLines when there is a linebreak. I want there to be an ellipses, but there is not. So it looks like that is all the text, but really, there is a line break and more lines to follow.

Answer (score 770):

## Use the [`numberOfLines`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#numberoflines) parameter on a `Text` component:

```html
<Text numberOfLines={1}>long long long long text<Text>
```

Will produce:

```
long long long…
```

*(Assuming you have short width container.)*

---

#### Use the [`ellipsizeMode`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#ellipsizemode) parameter to move the ellipsis to the `head` or `middle`. `tail` is the default value.

```html
<Text numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode='head'>long long long long text<Text>
```

Will produce:

```
…long long text
```

---

**NOTE:** The `Text` component should also include `style={{ flex: 1 }}` when the ellipsis needs to be applied relative to the size of its container. Useful for row layouts, etc.

Comment: Maybe obvious maybe not, need to specify width on the Text as well.

Comment: The interesting question is: how do you compute the number of lines? Because I guess nobody ever knows it in advance (since it has no reason to be static).

Comment: Nice answer, but if want the same behavior like css ellipses, need use **ellipsizeMode='tail'**.

Comment: @RanYefet you should consider marking this answer as the correct one, it would help others, thanks!

Comment: @Goutham The closest you will get is ellipsizeMode set to middle I think.

Comment: I add my answer too, but this answer is better. thank you

Comment: `style={{ flexShrink: 1 }}` can be used instead of `flex: 1` if you don't want the element to grow in a row layout

Answer (score 88):

You can use ellipsizeMode and numberOfLines.
e.g

```js
<Text ellipsizeMode='tail' numberOfLines={2}>
  This very long text should be truncated with dots in the beginning.
</Text>
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html

Comment: As long as the container of the Text element has a Flex value (I use, 1), the text will be truncated within the container.

Comment: ellipsizeMode='tail' is not needed as 'tail' is default value for ellipsizeMode.
Unless you want to show ellipse in beginning of the text, you can use just numberOfLines prop and it should work.

Answer (score 34):

```
<Text ellipsizeMode='tail' numberOfLines={2} style={{width:100}}>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam at cursus 
</Text>
```

Result inside box:

```
<-- width = 100-->
 -----------------
| Lorem ipsum     |
| dolar sit a...  |
 -----------------
```

Answer (score 18):

```
<View 
   style={{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        padding: 10,
    }}
>
  <Text numberOfLines={5} style={{flex:1}}>
       This is a very long text that will overflow on a small device This is a very 
       long text that will overflow on a small deviceThis is a very long text that 
       will overflow on a small deviceThis is a very long text that will overflow 
       on a small device
  </Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 4):

To Achieve ellipses for the text use the Text property numberofLines={1} which will automatically truncate the text with an ellipsis you can specify the ellipsizeMode as "head", "middle", "tail" or "clip"
By default it is tail

https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#ellipsizemode

Answer (score 2):

If you want **read more** behavior, then you can use the `react-native-read-more-text` library:

`npm i react-native-read-more-text --save`

```js
<ReadMore
  numberOfLines={1}
  renderTruncatedFooter={(handlePress) => { return <Text onPress={handlePress} style={{ color: 'grey' }}>show more</Text> }}
  renderRevealedFooter={(handlePress) => { return <Text onPress={handlePress} style={{ color: 'grey' }}>show less</Text> }}
>
  <Text>yourText</Text>
</ReadMore>
```

Docs: https://github.com/expo/react-native-read-more-text

To hide "read more" when the content is less than **numberOfLines**, you can use ternary operator:

```js
{
  'yourText'.length > 50
  ?
  <ReadMore
    numberOfLines={1}
    renderTruncatedFooter={(handlePress) => { return <Text onPress={handlePress} style={{ color: 'grey' }}>show more</Text> }}
    renderRevealedFooter={(handlePress) => { return <Text onPress={handlePress} style={{ color: 'grey' }}>show less</Text> }}
  >
    <Text>yourText</Text>
  </ReadMore>
  :
  <Text>yourText</Text>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<Text numberOfLines={1}>long long long long text<Text>
```

exchangeTypeText: {
width: "85%",
overflow: "hidden",

},

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> Here is JSX vertion if some one using simple react ,, not knowing react native though

```
import { useState } from "react";
    
    function ElipseText({ text, size = 500 }) {
      const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(true)
      const renderText = (text) => {
        let textJSX = text;
        if (showMore) {
          textJSX = text.substring(0, size);
        }
        return (<span className="elipse-text">
          <p className="text01" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: textJSX }} />
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <a className="btn01" onClick={() => setShowMore(!showMore)}>
            {!showMore && <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path fill="currentColor" d="M497.333 239.999H80.092l95.995-95.995l-22.627-22.627L18.837 256L153.46 390.623l22.627-22.627l-95.997-95.997h417.243v-32z"></path></svg>}
            {showMore ? "Show More" : "Show Less"}
            {showMore && <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 15 15"><path fill="currentColor" fillRule="evenodd" d="M9.854 3.146L14.207 7.5l-4.353 4.354l-.708-.708L12.293 8H1V7h11.293L9.146 3.854l.708-.708Z" clipRule="evenodd"></path></svg>}
          </a>
        </span>)
      }
    
      return (
        <>
          {renderText(text)}
        </>
      )
    }
    
    export default ElipseText
```

> SCSS File

```
.elipse-text {
  .btn01 {
    display: inline-flex;
    color: var(--color-dark);
    align-items: center;
    gap: 0.5rem;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-dark);
  }

  .text01 {
    display: contents;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -20):

```css
const styles = theme => ({
 contentClass:{
    overflow: 'hidden',
    textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
    display: '-webkit-box',
    WebkitLineClamp:1,
    WebkitBoxOrient:'vertical'
 }   
})
```

```html
render () {
  return(
    <div className={classes.contentClass}>
      {'content'}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: the question is more about React Native, where textOverflow is not a valid prop