# Set max length of characters to a Text in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I Know you can use maxLength to decide how many characters allowed in a text input, but is there any similar property to the Text  ?

as you see in the picture here the text runs out of the screen, i want to set it to something like

```
<Text maxLength={20}> Text Inside Here </Text>
```

Image of the use case:

[image: list with text that runs off the right-hand side]

Comment: Just to be hyper-clear, you're talking about limiting the *display* of text (since `Text` is for text display), not the *input* of text (which would be `TextInput`). Along the lines of CSS's `text-overflow: ellipsis` or similar?

Comment: Your tips about text-overflow got me searching and finding the solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594080/how-to-have-ellipsis-effect-on-text?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa