# white-space and text-overflow styles doesn't works in react native

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, styled-components

I'm trying use *styled_components* to replace some texts when line is break with the follows *css* styles:

```css
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

But when i use *text-overflow* and/or *white-space* styles, i have a error, because textOverflow and whiteSpace is not a valid style property.

How to apply that styles with styled_components or React Native StyleSheet?

Thank you!

React, React Native e Styled Components version

```json
{
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.4",
"styled-components": "^5.2.1"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer for my question!

I just added numberOfLines and ellipsizeMode props to my text component and everything worked well.

[How to have Ellipsis effect on Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594080/how-to-have-ellipsis-effect-on-text)

Answer (score 0):

> The solution to that issue is flexShrink: 1.
>
> ```
> <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}> 
>  <Text style={{ flexShrink: 1 }}>
>   Really really long text...
>  </Text>
> </View>
> ```
>
> Depending on your set up, you may also also need to add flexShrink: 1
> to the 's parent as well, to get this to work, so play with that
> and you'll make it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57462018/18021672

Comment: Thank you! 

I found the resolution for this "problem", i just added numberOfLines and ellipsizeMode props to my text component and worked well.