# Make text line don't break on flexbox child element ( React Native )

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

### SOLVED (solution at the end)

I have the following layout, I want the text `SOME LOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG TEXT` to don´t break the line and show an ellipse.

E.x.: `Pangaré Figueiredo SOME LOOOOOO...`

```
const LastHighline = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity className="my-3 flex-row items-center gap-x-3">
      <View className="flex-initial">
        <HistorySvg />
      </View>

      <Text className="flex-1 overflow-hidden whitespace-nowrap overflow-ellipsis">{props.name} SOME LOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG TEXT</Text>

      <View className="flex-shrink-0 flex-row items-center">
        <HeightSvg />
        <Text>{props.height}m</Text>
      </View>
      <View className="flex-shrink-0 flex-row items-center gap-x-2">
        <WidthSvg />
        <Text>{props.length}m</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

[image]

## Solution

Just put `flex-1` in order to make the element shrink and grow when necessary, and the `truncate` was substituted with a property of `<Text>` tag named `numberOfLines`, set to 1 and got the expected result

check the resource here [How to have Ellipsis effect on Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594080/how-to-have-ellipsis-effect-on-text)

```
<Text className="flex-1" numberOfLines={1}>{props.name} SOME LOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG TEXT</Text>`
```

Comment: Try to add tailwind `truncate` class to `<Text className="flex-1 overflow-hidden whitespace-nowrap overflow-ellipsis">{props.name} SOME LOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG TEXT</Text>`

Comment: the `truncate` class is a short-hand to `overflow-hidden whitespace-nowrap overflow-ellipsis`, but dind´t solve the line breaking problem

Comment: And if you add `w-full truncate` together? Or create example where it can be tested (a fiddle maybe).

Comment: Solution was to put a property of `<Text>` tag `numberOfLines={1}`

Answer (score 2):

#### EDIT

Here is a similar layout to what you're doing.  Your issue is that you need to have a bounding box to container the text, and cause it to overflow.

Here is an example

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: colmun;
  gap: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

section .box {
  background: red;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  display: block;
}

p {
  /* You need to limit the size of the text box */
  width: 50px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


/* If you want to have the second line show, wrap it in a span like this. */
.second p {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.second span {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<section class="first">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <p>Text LOOOONNNNNGGGGGGG TEXTTTTT</p>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</section>

<section class="second">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <p>Text <span>LOOOONNNNNGGGGGGG TEXTTTTT</span></p>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</section>
```

#### Here is a very minimal working version of `text-overflow: ellipsis;`

##### See [MDN's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) for more information.

```css
section {
  background: red;
  width: 250px;  
}

.text-overflow h1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Hello World! LOOOOOOONNNNNNGGGGG TEXT</h1>
</section>

<section class="text-overflow">
  <h1>Hello World! LOOOOOOONNNNNNGGGGG TEXT</h1>
</section>
```